# url - ajax loaded but no JS

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, callbacks

I have this url to call the taxonomy.php by pressing the button with the code beneath to show filtered posts:

```
http://myurl/?meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC
```

This is the JS I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$("#hot a").click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel")
    $(".postbox_wrapper").html('<span class="filter_posts"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/images/287.gif"></span>');
    $(".postbox_wrapper").load(jQuery(this).attr("href") + " .postbox_wrapper")
    return false;
});
```

});

The call works perfectly - the content show up without pagereload - as I wish.

The problem is, that JS is not loaded on the ajaxloaded pages and I really don't get it to load. I tried out many versions, I found on stackexchange, but nothing worked out.

For example this needs to be loaded into the ajaxed call: `http://myname.disqus.com/count.js?ver=3.4.1`

Has anybody an idea?

Thanky you very much.

AD

Comment: I think this is maybe beyond the scope of WordPress Answers, as it's not specific to WordPress. You're not loading a *page* via AJAX, you're *loading specific elements from one DOM into an existing DOM*.

Comment: Are you saying you want JS to load on the actual AJAX call? If for some reason that's the case, you might need to dig into server-side vs. client-side processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in your `complete` callback of the `load` function:

```
$(".postbox_wrapper").load(
    jQuery(this).attr("href") + " .postbox_wrapper",
    function(response, status, xhr) { // complete callback

        // create a empty div
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        // fill div with response
        div.innerHTML = response;
        // take correct part of the response
        var ref = $($(div).find('.postbox_wrapper').html());
        // filter response for script tags
        ref.filter('script').each(function () {
            // execute the scripts
            $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '');
        });
    }
});
```

I would also also recommend that you add a error message if the call fails.
See example 2 on http://api.jquery.com/load/

I had a hard time to figure that out, I tried all the answers found on stackoverflow.
Finally I found this german site. There you can see the full code: http://labor.99grad.de/flash/agentur/wiesbaden/jquery/script-tag-bei-ajax-response-ausfuhren/

Comment: Hi Xsonic - thank you very much for th reply. I tried your code. It seems to be exactly what I need. It's not working so far - where should I put the code exactly? Thank you!!

Comment: I edited the code above to make it cealrer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$("#fokus a").click(function(){

    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(".postbox_wrapper").html('<span class="filter_posts"><img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/images/287.gif"></span>');
    $(".postbox_wrapper").load((jQuery(this).attr("href") + " .postbox_wrapper"), function() {
    //$.globalEval('http://check.disqus.com/count.js?ver=3.4.1');
        $.getScript("http://check.disqus.com/count.js?ver=3.4.1", function() {
            //alert('first Load was performed.');
        },false);
    });
    //alert('second Load was performed.');
    return false;
    });
```

This works so far. Thank you for your help!

AD